# Heremaps error 414 on calculate route API

Tags: routes, here-api

can you help us on how we can fix the issue related to error 414 on calculate route on heremaps? We are passing a total of 160 waypoints. Are there any limitations on heremaps? Thanks.

GET https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json net::ERR_ABORTED 414

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=<APPID>&app_code=<APPCODE>&routeattributes=sh&mode=fastest%3Bcar&waypoint0=geo!45.50549871423571%2C-73.57643627776505&waypoint1=geo!45.50606493439499%2C-73.57643187046051&waypoint2=geo!45.50606493439499%2C-73.57643187046051&waypoint3=geo!45.50635066062972%2C-73.57670545578003&waypoint4=geo!45.50691628463841%2C-73.57696735515&waypoint5=geo!45.50702737487426%2C-73.5761421918869&waypoint6=geo!45.50799634291375%2C-73.57478940142992&waypoint7=geo!45.50754144928726%2C-73.57395791663531&waypoint8=geo!45.50774543498208%2C-73.57343852519989&waypoint9=geo!45.507534905218954%2C-73.57295036315918&waypoint10=geo!45.50792405346184%2C-73.57190870894793&waypoint11=geo!45.50792405346184%2C-73.57190870894793&waypoint12=geo!45.508444688901506%2C-73.57180774211884&waypoint13=geo!45.50865897465402%2C-73.5722690820694&waypoint14=geo!45.50907366533914%2C-73.57344759850673&waypoint15=geo!45.509148852575194%2C-73.57373727708034&waypoint16=geo!45.509468397207996%2C-73.57404304890804&waypoint17=geo!45.50965896404607%2C-73.57370138168335&waypoint18=geo!45.50940332935043%2C-73.57310056686401&waypoint19=geo!45.5092938442692%2C-73.57265902905635&waypoint20=geo!45.508948447094554%2C-73.57218861579895&waypoint21=geo!45.508767532863374%2C-73.5715861454504&waypoint22=geo!45.50900483765645%2C-73.57057392597198&waypoint23=geo!45.50859506495355%2C-73.57097625732422&waypoint24=geo!45.50826423710875%2C-73.57085287570953&waypoint25=geo!45.50810211782756%2C-73.57015384583644&waypoint26=geo!45.50784824219169%2C-73.56940009107416&waypoint27=geo!45.50784824219169%2C-73.56940009107416&waypoint28=geo!45.50784824219169%2C-73.56940009107416&waypoint29=geo!45.50784824219169%2C-73.56940009107416&waypoint30=geo!45.50784824219169%2C-73.56940009107416&waypoint31=geo!45.50784824219169%2C-73.56940009107416&waypoint32=geo!45.50784824219169%2C-73.56940009107416&waypoint33=geo!45.50784824219169%2C-73.56940009107416&waypoint34=geo!45.50784824219169%2C-73.56940009107416&waypoint35=geo!45.50784824219169%2C-73.56940009107416&waypoint36=geo!45.50784824219169%2C-73.56940009107416&waypoint37=geo!45.50794222826721%2C-73.56703438272302&waypoint38=geo!45.50852363637892%2C-73.56522023677826&waypoint39=geo!45.5080971860659%2C-73.56457747926538&waypoint40=geo!45.507185822684725%2C-73.5652104805929&waypoint41=geo!45.5069446657919%2C-73.56608927249908&waypoint42=geo!45.50669653781557%2C-73.56633067131042&waypoint43=geo!45.50670460585652%2C-73.56705584039514&waypoint44=geo!45.50702040486405%2C-73.56739379873102&waypoint45=geo!45.50637321790227%2C-73.567333817482&waypoint46=geo!45.506182029797834%2C-73.56735624780481&waypoint47=geo!45.50592333605151%2C-73.56686272134607&waypoint48=geo!45.505073665752946%2C-73.5676781128866&waypoint49=geo!45.50538820858034%2C-73.56797218322754&waypoint50=geo!45.50531804126768%2C-73.56878318300073&waypoint51=geo!45.505991008355764%2C-73.56921770086115&waypoint52=geo!45.505013511617385%2C-73.5693893622381&waypoint53=geo!45.50461122918353%2C-73.56880464067285&waypoint54=geo!45.5046375468138%2C-73.57046224584406&waypoint55=geo!45.50374443604083%2C-73.57018866052454&waypoint56=geo!45.503492970633474%2C-73.57122388942503&waypoint57=geo!45.50306096160393%2C-73.57080459594727&waypoint58=geo!45.50259814610915%2C-73.57142773731016&waypoint59=geo!45.502865091048264%2C-73.57201782329344&waypoint60=geo!45.503440334290424%2C-73.57268301112913&waypoint61=geo!45.50376367104876%2C-73.57235578162931&waypoint62=geo!45.50442161802042%2C-73.57176569564604&waypoint63=geo!45.5050006049947%2C-73.57134190662168&waypoint64=geo!45.505564547621454%2C-73.57081619365476&waypoint65=geo!45.50569989301125%2C-73.57155648334287&waypoint66=geo!45.50515850949965%2C-73.57285467250608&waypoint67=geo!45.50501976554983%2C-73.57233345508575&waypoint68=geo!45.504474253445984%2C-73.5731819020059&waypoint69=geo!45.504640041127715%2C-73.572558760643&waypoint70=geo!45.50520738461381%2C-73.573739801481&waypoint71=geo!45.50584651681628%2C-73.57355204684995&waypoint72=geo!45.506429248676625%2C-73.57335892780088&waypoint73=geo!45.50647848505468%2C-73.5726660490036&waypoint74=geo!45.50705708851067%2C-73.57259718044065&waypoint75=geo!45.50636214261705%2C-73.57107449293134&waypoint76=geo!45.50657267676641%2C-73.57005525350569&waypoint77=geo!45.506835843345826%2C-73.56887508153913&waypoint78=geo!45.50724186936918%2C-73.57005525350569&waypoint79=geo!45.50764017019894%2C-73.5714590549469&waypoint80=geo!45.50665983184891%2C-73.57423949956892&waypoint81=geo!45.50609125134569%2C-73.57491374015808&waypoint82=geo!45.50472740255826%2C-73.57452917814253&waypoint83=geo!45.50341150807294%2C-73.5756771636009&waypoint84=geo!45.50309568881966%2C-73.574615008831&waypoint85=geo!45.50253459192002%2C-73.57551455497742&waypoint86=geo!45.502196208810155%2C-73.57573986053467&waypoint87=geo!45.50226853475987%2C-73.57650328397749&waypoint88=geo!45.502057984513364%2C-73.57659984350202&waypoint89=geo!45.50151057342211%2C-73.57629943609236&waypoint90=geo!45.501451758809495%2C-73.5774028301239&waypoint91=geo!45.501269941265114%2C-73.57908893346784&waypoint92=geo!45.50061706073937%2C-73.58035326004028&waypoint93=geo!45.50154199569748%2C-73.58054637908936&waypoint94=geo!45.502661456693204%2C-73.58163166761396&waypoint95=geo!45.50359516677721%2C-73.57827354192732&waypoint96=geo!45.50430919003823%2C-73.57963442802429&waypoint97=geo!45.50479042734378%2C-73.57715606689453&waypoint98=geo!45.505722812916595%2C-73.57867956161499&waypoint99=geo!45.506120714933424%2C-73.58231524294543&waypoint100=geo!45.50661006871835%2C-73.58232736587524&waypoint101=geo!45.507835661782366%2C-73.57969880104065&waypoint102=geo!45.50872135192726%2C-73.57894638842272&waypoint103=geo!45.510234137866185%2C-73.57903361320496&waypoint104=geo!45.5115433710521%2C-73.57740143603014&waypoint105=geo!45.5111213225601%2C-73.57665181159973&waypoint106=geo!45.51092584238809%2C-73.57596516609192&waypoint107=geo!45.50999473891567%2C-73.57575992411303&waypoint108=geo!45.51039322360139%2C-73.57672551935839&waypoint109=geo!45.507986039461464%2C-73.57512831687927&waypoint110=geo!45.50786191952104%2C-73.57786992768168&waypoint111=geo!45.50716265836207%2C-73.57930759171366&waypoint112=geo!45.50675663176735%2C-73.57814887741922&waypoint113=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint113=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint114=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint115=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint116=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint117=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint118=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint119=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint120=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint121=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint122=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint123=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint124=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint125=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint126=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint127=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint128=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint129=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint130=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint131=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint132=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint133=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint134=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint135=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint136=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint137=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint138=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint139=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint140=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint141=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint142=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint143=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint144=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint145=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint146=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint147=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint148=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint149=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint150=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint151=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint152=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint153=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint154=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint155=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint156=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint157=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint158=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint159=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&waypoint160=geo!45.506245334852444%2C-73.57768753746866&jsoncallback=H.service.jsonp.handleResponse(707)
```

Comment: Can you post the exact URL query and exact response which you get?

Comment: Please share URL which allow us to look more details to debug, However standard waypoints are limited to 100 only

Comment: Hello, Kindly see the updated question which added the actual URL. Kindly change the app id and app code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HERE Routing API is an HTTP JSON REST API that provides route calculation between two or more locations for several regions in the world

These newly released versions of HERE Location Services provide a unified API framework while leveraging the HERE platform, making it easy and efficient for any customer to adapt the breadth of our Location Services offering and beyond. however, you’re still using app_id and app_code, please check out the documentation posted at https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management where you will find information on how to create and use new credentials

Please refer to the migration guide to Routing API V8 as follows :
https://developers.here.com/documentation/routing-api/migration_guide/index.html

Also, example for Route Via Intermediate Waypoint :

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/via.html

Comment: Do you have any recommendations to load more than 100 waypoints? Thanks.